# Paypal Donations Thermometer Needed

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

i'm on the hunt & coming up short for a simple **thermometer, meter, progress bar**, or something similar that can automatically track how much is given via a **Paypal Donation Button**, & show how far it has to go to reach a set goal.

we don't need suggestions for sites like `GoFundMe.com` & the like. and we are **NOT using Wordpress**! just need a **PHP** &/or **Javascript/Jquery** script that can use Paypal's ***current*** API/IPN & animate a visual indicator of how much has come in & how much there is to go in a fundraiser.

i HAVE done my due diligence & am at a loss. 
i like the Progress Bar `TotalDonations.com` has, but don't need all that other stuff. besides, it's a Wordpress plugin.
i really like the Thermometer at `AprendaGames.com/wordpress-goal-thermometer-widget` has, but again, it's a Wordpress plugin :-(

i know Paypal had a widget some years ago, but not anymore. oh, and do NOT want anything that relies on Flash.

if nothing like what i'm wanting exists, then i'm willing to hear how much it would cost & how long it would take to make one.

thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need a plugin for this and looking at plugins that aren't compatible doesn't really count as due diligence. Having said that, you can use Paypal's API to track donations, Jquery to animate the bar when a donation is made, and any progress bar tutorial for Javascript in order to make the actual bar.

Comment: uhm, thanks William... i think. i guess i should have spent more time crafting my text, as what you said is what i know, but since i don't "know" how to code anything other than html/css, i'm looking for help finding one pre-done or making one. and yes, if all i did was search for plugins, you're right, that wouldn't be due diligence. but i've done a LOT more than that over the past week which i don't think should be listed out. when i've done that in the past, the moderators have moderated me.

Answer (score 1):

Check out codepen there is a Donation Progress Bar open-sourced at: /stemlund/pen/Bkvyj
It has HTML/CSS just add the